# How to map the picklist in Salesforce to Radio Buttons in DocuSign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, radio-group, picklist, docusignapextoolkit

I have a field in Salesforce that is a picklist type (dropdown list). When a user picks an option from the picklist, and selects the "send with DocuSign" button in Salesforce, I want to have an appropriate radio button to be selected inside Docusign.

[radio buttons in DocuSign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9KIN.png)     ->      [picklist in Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1AQd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the DocuSign Custom Radio Button Group

- In DocuSign, go to My Preferences > Custom Fields
- Click Add New Field
- Select the Type of Radio Button from the drop-down
- Enter the Radio Button Group Name in the Name field (i.e. My Radio Buttons)
- Enter the desired Radio Button Value in the Tooltip field (i.e. Radio One)
- Click Save
- Repeat steps if you have more than one button

Then create a custom DocuSign connect object

- In DocuSign Admin go to Connect and Select your Salesforce Connect Configuration
- Under Connect Objects, select New Object > Salesforce Object
- Select Activate Object
- Enter a Name for your Object in the Object Name field (i.e. My Radio Button to Picklist Test)
- Under Select Salesforce Object, pick the Object you are sending from (i.e. Opportunity)
- Under Select Where > Saleforce.com Field, select Opportunity ID (id)
- Under Select Where > DocuSign Field, select Envelope External Source ID
- Under Update Fields > Saleforce.com Field, select the Picklist you created in Salesforce (i.e. My Picklist)
- Under Update Fields > DocuSign Field, select Recipient Secure Field, then enter the name of your Radio Button Group (i.e. My Radio Buttons)
- Click Save

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact thing and it is not working for me. Do you know if anything has change since you answered this?

Comment: This also works with Custom Objects?